# Editing Libreoffice Calc spreadsheets in the terminal

Tags: terminal, libreoffice, spreadsheet

Is there an app to edit LO Calc spreadsheets in the terminal, i.e. in text mode w/o the GUI?.

It doesn't need to be a LO package, anything will do. It needs to be able to save in Calc's .ods format.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you need to save in .ODS? The `Calc` is able to open .csv by itself, there is no need to do a pre-convertion.

But if you really want to play with .ods outside of `Calc` - you can use Perl, with modules like `Spreadsheet::ParseODS` or `ODF::lpOD`.

For Python, there is `pyexcel-ods` module.

Or, for true geniuses, the Calc has its own dialect of Visual Basic for Application, which allows to import data into the spreadsheet, format it in any way and export back however you like.

Comment: Thanks. Saving in ODS is needed in case the file should be edited in the future in Calc. Isn't there a text-based spreadsheet which can import/export ODS?.

Comment: @jzz11 CSV - the most versatile

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on user-friendly CSV terminal-based editors?. I'm looking for something which is intuitive to use, displays CSV data as tables/spreadsheet cells, and allows simple navigation.

Comment: https://lock.cmpxchg8b.com/spreadsheet.html

Comment: Great, thanks 